# How Spring handle AuthenticationServiceException compared to BadCredentialsException thown from AbstractUserDetailsAuthenticationProvider

Tags: spring-security

When I threw a `BadCredentialsException` from `AbstractUserDetailsAuthenticationProvider's` concrete class with a message, it has been handled by spring and appropriate message present in the default failure jsp is displayed.

But when `AuthenticationServiceException` is thrown from same class, spring is not able to handle it rather is displaying a stack trace. I observe that in this case the spring is not able to redirect to the default failure jsp.

1. Both BadCredentialsException and AuthenticationServiceException  are subclasses of AuthenticationException, then why is spring security handling in different ways?
2. Is there any place where his configurain needs to be set up?
3. Is there any specific reason why AuthenticationServiceException  is not handled?

Comment: Is your not handled exception thrown when user is trying to authenticate?

Comment: Post your code/cofiguration. We don't like to guess. Tell us when this exception is thrown.